# Git remote was set but others could not see my pushes?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-remote

First of all, it was working fine. I can push and I can pull.

I do remember my previous push was rejected even though I have done the pull.

And also I accidentally started a rebase and I pushed with "-f" to ignore the "remote reject"

Then I cancelled the rebase and started a normal push again. Although it was accepted by the remote, somehow others are not seeing my changes as if I were in a different branch.

I have checked multiple times that I am in the same branch and my remote url is correct.

So could any one tell me what happened to my git repo and suggest any troubleshooting process?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the output of `git status` and `git remote -v` and `git rev-list BRANCH -3` and `git rev-list REMOTE/BRANCH -3`

Comment: BTW it is odd that you pushed while in the middle of a rebase (detached HEAD mode). Have no idea what the ramifications of that are.

Comment: Thanks guys for you comment. I guess its the rebase that messed up the git repo. I have recreate a local git repo and fix the issue. Still thanks for all of your answers. Since this question won't add value to any others I will close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Try `git branch` to see which branches you have in existence and what your current branch is.
2. Try `git push --all --dry-run` to see what needs to be pushed out to your remote. This will show you, for all branches, what it would push if you ran `git push --all`, and where to. Unless you specify `--all`, only the current branch will be pushed. This may be your problem -- you might still be in detached-head mode from the rebase, which you might not have correctly canceled (correctly using `git rebase --abort`). You might get an error here and need to give `-f`, which is safe **as long as** you use `--dry-run`.
3. Assuming your remote is on GitHub or Bitbucket, go look on that site at your remote and see what actually is pushed there.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I guess its the rebase that messed up the git repo. I have recreate a local git repo and fix the issue. Still thanks for all of your answers. Since this question won't add value to any others I will close it.